# Fancy Tree Icon alignment as vertical center

Tags: html, css, fancytree

I am trying to place the file icon in vertically at center position.

please see the below Image

[image]

Here is the [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tlmVmUgjJWeHJ4L3pnHm?p=preview)

the file Icon and check box must be place in center, i.e with the text for better look and feel.

I tried using `vertical-align : middle` But no luck.

Here is DOM element structure

```
<div id="tree" class="ui-draggable-handle">

    <ul class="ui-fancytree fancytree-container fancytree-plain fancytree-ext-edit fancytree-ext-glyph" tabindex="0">

        <li class="">
            <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-expanded fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-e">
                <span class="fancytree-expander "></span>
                <span class="fancytree-checkbox glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
                <span class="fancytree-icon glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
                <span class="fancytree-title"><h1>Format</h1></span>
            </span>
        </li>

        <li class="fancytree-lastsib">
            <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-expanded fancytree-lastsib fancytree-exp-nl fancytree-ico-e">
                <span class="fancytree-expander "></span>
                <span class="fancytree-checkbox glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
                <span class="fancytree-icon glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
                <span class="fancytree-title">
                    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
                </span>
            </span>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share a minimal running copy of your code so that it would be easy to look into.

Comment: @JVM Added plunkr in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy and dynamic:

```
span.fancytree-title,
span.fancytree-icon,
span.fancytree-expander{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Y69kSNUtyKEARF3CfOhh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

@Gaurav - I have fixed the vertical alignment for your code. Basically, I am overriding the margins provided by fancytree and default margins of Heading Tags (H1, H2 etc) using embedded stylesheet. 
Take a look [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NkBSTBZjNt18wpjWem9g?p=preview)

```
 <style>
  span.fancytree-expander, span.fancytree-icon {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  }
  span.fancytree-title {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  }
  h1 {
   margin: -10px 0 5px 0;
  }
  h2 {
   margin: -5px 0 0 0;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: h1 and h2 tags are just an illustrate, I wand to arrange icon based on fancytree title. fancytree title is generate dynamically.

Comment: Can titles have different font sizes also?

Comment: Yes, Its generate dynamically so its hard to determine the font size.